# I have two methods with ActionResult return types yet one of them is giving back a single Employee object and still works. Why is that?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've just wrote a controller class in a Blazor application and I don't undersand something.
I have a method GetEmployee:

```
[HttpGet("{employeeId:int}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> GetEmployee(int employeeId)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await employeeRepsitory.GetEmployee(employeeId);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    NotFound();
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    "Error retrieving data from the database");
            }
        }
```

The return type is an `ActionResult<Employee>` but clearly in my method I'm returning an Employee. Because the `employeeRepsitory.GetEmployee(employeeId)` method gives back a single Employee which is stored in a variable "result".
I have an other method GetEmployees :

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Employee>>> GetEmployees()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(await employeeRepsitory.GetEmployees());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    "Error retrieving data from the database");
            }
        }
```

Where I put my object in an `Ok()` ActionResult. If I didn't wrap `await employeeRepsitory.GetEmployees()` in an `Ok()` then I have compillation error because I'm not giving back ActionResult. But how does that `GetEmployee(int employeeId)` method is not giving me compilation error yet I'm clearly giving back an Employee object and not an ActionResult. Thank you for your answers.